# How to extract a number from a string based on a preceding pattern using stringr?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I would like to extract the values for HBA1C. These values appear after the pattern "HBA1C = " in the text variable `X2` of the dataframe `df`. The pattern can appear at the start of the string as in rows 2, 3 and 6, as well as in the middle as in row 4.

```
df<-data.frame(X1=1:6,X2=c(NA,"HBA1C = 8.9 (09/06/15)","HBA1C = 9.8 (03/08/15)",
                           "JUN 2014, WAS ON LANTUS AND APIDARA HBA1C = 6.2 (21/7/15), 
                           NEHR LOCKED. 18/8/15","SLIDING SCALE FOLLOWED STRICTLY",
                           "HBA1C = 11.7 (17/7/15)"))

# df
#  X1                                                                              X2
#1  1                                                                            <NA>
#2  2                                                          HBA1C = 8.9 (09/06/15)
#3  3                                                          HBA1C = 9.8 (03/08/15)
#4  4 JUN 2014, WAS ON LANTUS AND APIDARA HBA1C = 6.2 (21/7/15), NEHR LOCKED. 18/8/15
#5  5                                                 SLIDING SCALE FOLLOWED STRICTLY
#6  6                                                          HBA1C = 11.7 (17/7/15)
```

These values that I would like to extract should be save in a new variable, `X3`, as follows:

```
# df
#  X1                                                                              X2   X3
#1  1                                                                            <NA>   NA
#2  2                                                          HBA1C = 8.9 (09/06/15)  8.9
#3  3                                                          HBA1C = 9.8 (03/08/15)  9.8
#4  4 JUN 2014, WAS ON LANTUS AND APIDARA HBA1C = 6.2 (21/7/15), NEHR LOCKED. 18/8/15  6.2
#5  5                                                 SLIDING SCALE FOLLOWED STRICTLY   NA
#6  6                                                          HBA1C = 11.7 (17/7/15) 11.7
```

I tried the following code, but it would not work.

```
library(stringr)
df1$X3 <- 
str_extract(str_extract(df$X2,pattern = "HBA1C = [0-9].[0-9]"),pattern = "[0-9].[0-9]")
```

I received this error:

> Error in df$X2 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a single `str_extract` with regex lookarounds

```
df$X3 <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$X2,pattern = "(?<=HBA1C \\= )[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"))
df$X3
#[1]   NA  8.9  9.8  6.2   NA 11.7
```

The `pattern` matching are one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) followed by a `.` followed by one or more numbers that succeeds the word 'HBA1C' followed by a space, `=` and space

NOTE: Some characters are meta i.e. they are perceived by the regex engine differently i.e. for example `.` it implies any character instead of the literal dot (`.`).  So, for those cases, we have to escape (`\\`) or place it inside the square brackets `[.]`